# My productcontext keeps showing up as undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-context

Im trying to use context in react, its beeen a while since ive used it. Trying to debug when i print out productConsumer variable i get undefined. Can anyone help me fix this?

```
import { ProductContext } from '../../pages/oniContext';
function Contact(props) {
    const productConsumer = useContext(ProductContext);

  useEffect(() => {
   console.log("ProductContext",productConsumer)
  }, [ProductContext])
```

Here is my context file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const ProductContext = React.createContext();



export default class ProductProvider extends Component {
                 state = {
                   name: '',
                   number: '',
                   message: '',
                   email: '',
                   messageSent: false,
                 };

                 render() {
                   return (
                     <ProductContext.Provider
                       value={{
                         ...this.state,

                       }}
                     >
                       {this.props.children}
                     </ProductContext.Provider>
                   );
                 }
               }

const ProductConsumer = ProductContext.Consumer;

export { ProductProvider, ProductConsumer, ProductContext };
```

Comment: I assume `ProductProvider` is a parent of `Contact`?

Comment: Did you wrap the component using `ProductProvider` ?

Comment: how do you `export default class ProductProvider` and then `export { ProductProvider, ...` again?

Comment: I did not wrap it i thought i just had to use usecontext

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to wrap my Main APP Component AS Amila Said
Also